# Is there a "light" version of GIMP?

Tags: gimp

Once, while on the internet I ran across a "light" version of GIMP that I have since never been able to find again.  Does anyone know the link or know how to find the light version of GIMP?

I know it exists , because I saw it once.  Just trying to find it.

Comment: sure you mean 'light' and not 'portable'? http://portableapps.com/apps/graphics_pictures/gimp_portable

Comment: yep, I am not talking about portable.  i am looking for a Gimp that loads much faster because it loads fewer plugins on startup.

Comment: I'll leave this open waiting for an answer but I found something that works pretty good for me.  Its a free program called FotoGraphics .

Comment: sure you mean FotoGraphics and not FotoGrafix? :)

Comment: oops.  i meant FotoGrafix ... yep.

Comment: yep, FotoGrafix is amazing, given the size. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer turns out to be something called "[GimPhoto](http://www.gimphoto.com/)".

Answer (score 5):

If you're on Windows, try [Paint.NET](http://www.getpaint.net/)

Comment: Paint.Net is not related to Gimp.  Its an ok suggestion though.

Answer (score 3):

If you're on OSX, have a look at [Seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/). From the website:

> Seashore is an open source image editor for Mac OS X's Cocoa framework. It features gradients, textures and anti-aliasing for both text and brush strokes. It supports multiple layers and alpha channel editing. It is based around the GIMP's technology and uses the same native file format.
>
> However, unlike the GIMP, Seashore only aims to serve the basic image editing needs of most computer users, not to provide a replacement for professional image editing products.

I would call that a 'light' version ;-)

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, the only well known GIMP "alternative" version I remember is [GIMPShop](http://www.gimpshop.com/),

> intended to replicate the feel of
>   Adobe Photoshop. Its primary purpose is to make users of Photoshop feel comfortable using GIMP.

Comment: yeah, thats not quite the one i am looking for.  i lost the link but I definitely saw a ultra-light version of Gimp on the net somewhere.   still trying to find it...

Comment: I've searched for "GIMP Lite" and "GIMP Light" on google and haven't found too. Are you sure it was a GIMP version?

Answer (score 0):

I use Fotoxx for light weight needs when firing up the Gimp seems like overkill

https://kornelix.net/fotoxx/fotoxx.html

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please read [How to recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/a/5330/213131) for **minimum required information** and other suggestions on how to recommend software on Super User.  To keep your answer useful even if included link(s) breaks please [edit] these details into your answer.